# $0$-th homotopy set of $G\times Z_2/H$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups

For a connected Lie group $G$ and its subgroup $H$, if $\pi_0(G/H) = 1$, is it true $\pi_0(\frac{G\times Z_2}{H}) = \{1,-1\}$ and  $\pi_0(\frac{G\times Z_2}{H\times Z_2}) = 1$?

I have to understand something about the homotopy theory, but I don't have a mathematics background and don't know where I can find some theorem or explanation for the above question. Can anyone give me some hits? Either plain text explanation or introductory level references would be very appreciate!!!

Comment: What are $G$ and $H$? Notice that $\pi_0$ sees path components, not components.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry I didn't make it clear. $G$ is a connected manifold, e.g. $SO(3)$ and $H$ is a subgroup of it. In the case $G = SO(3)$, $G\times Z_2$ will be $O(3)$.

Comment: Do you mean that $G$ is a connected Lie group?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes.